# Blender camera problem

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

when I hit numpad 0 blender focus to object not the camera and when I try to render ı see black screen. You can see this problem on this video. How can I fix this?

https://youtu.be/bgg6i_4iMNA

Edit:
I solved the problem. You can see on the my answer or click the link.

https://youtu.be/2yDCiFCg_HU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem. The problem is local camera was my object you can see on the image.
[image]

now its fix :D

[image]

Comment: good, this is something useful for other people too :)

Answer (score 6):

the problem you are facing is that:

- what you see in the viewport is **not** what the camera sees (to check what camera views, click on the "camera icon" (check image below) or press <kbd>numpad 0</kbd>)
- the render is based on what the camera sees
- to match what the camera sees and what you see in the viewport you need to keep the two aligned.

To do it you should:

- click on the camera icon (or <kbd>numpad 0</kbd>)
- press <kbd>n</kbd> to open the right panel
- in the right panel, under View > View Lock, flag "lock / camera to view" (check the image below)
- when the "Lock / camera to view" is on, when you move your view in the spaceport, you also move the camera.

[image]
[image]

hope it helps

check also this to simplify all above:
[image]

Comment: Thanks man this helped.